# How to get token needed for hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(token, flags)?

Tags: java, android, service, input

So I am trying to make android IME. I need an ability to hide IME from my IME itself. 
So far i have seen only examples about how to show\hide IME from an activity, but I need to do it from IME.
I found out `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(token,flags)`, but it need token, and I cant figure out how to get it. `getCurrentInputBinding().getConnectionToken()` do not work - it crashes the application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, based on responses to this question in other places (I'm still trying to figure out a consistently working method myself), the token you need is from yourTextView.getWindowToken().

However, this isn't working for me, and I've seen many people with the same complaint.

[edit]
Using the above-specified token, I'm having better luck hiding the keyboard with hideSoftInputFromWindow instead of hideSoftInputFromInputMethod. Though since I didn't grasp the difference between these functions to begin with, I may not understand your actual question. Sorry!
[/edit]

Comment: I think he is trying to fill an EditText with a barcode reader, so he don't want the soft keyboard to be shown. I have tried many solutions, the main problem is getWindowToken() is null in an EditText. I will try with hideSoftInputFromWindow() as you suggest

Comment: @Windgate This question is eight and a half years old. Looking at the dates, it was already old when I answered it... considering how much Android can change from version to version, I definitely would not expect the advice here to be relevant any more. There's likely a different and/or better way to accomplish whatever this was about by now.

Comment: thanks for the clearification dude, but the problem today keep on being the same, all related post are a bundle of related code based on hideSoftInputFromWindow() and hideSoftInputFromInputMethod() and none of them work, the way Android let you hide/show keyboard is a weird mess